# How to add custom HTML to an Adobe Edge html page

Tags: html, adobe-edge

Adobe Edge replaces the project html file on every save.

How do I add custom HTML (e.g. a script tag) to that html file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it.

Open the project in Adobe Edge and save all your changes.

Edit the HTML file with an editor of your choice while your project **is still open in Adobe Edge**.

Save the file in the editor.
Switch back to Edge. You will be promped to reload the project like this:

*"index.html was changed outside of Edge Animate. 
Do you want to reload the composition? You will loose any unsaved changes."*

Click YES.

From this point on your changes will persist whenever you save the project.